# EF Core - detect actual property value changes

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to detect which fields/properties/columns have changed in DbContext's SaveChanges() method.  I'm currently using the following code:

```cs
string fields = "";
foreach (var entityProperty in ent.Entity.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var propertyName = entityProperty.Name;
    var currentValue = ent.Property(propertyName).CurrentValue;
    var originalValue = ent.Property(propertyName).OriginalValue;

if ( currentValue == null && originalValue != null ||
        originalValue == null && currentValue != null ||
    (currentValue != null && originalValue != null &&
    !originalValue.Equals(currentValue))                        
    )
{
    fields += propertyName + ", ";
    }
}
```

My code frequently sets the values of columns to their current value so I can't rely on PropertyEntry.IsModified - that seems to get set to true even if you set a field to the same value it already has.

Also, in the above code, originalValue is coming out as the NEW value of the column, so this code isn't working either.

Does anyone know how I can detect which fields/properties/columns have actually had their value changed?